# Font-Awesome doesn't load fonts

Tags: font-awesome

I'm trying to use Font-Awesome 4.2.0, I can see the css is loaded, but the fonts are not.  I'm am using Chrome, but have the same issue in FF and IE too.

I've created a stripped down version to demostrate this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  Remove It - <i class="fa-remove"></i>
</body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/eF6tPerRYOZHAdzzkdyk?p=preview

Obviously, I'd like to know how to solve this, but more importantly, I'd like to know how I can track down font problems better in the future.  Using the Chrome dev tools, I can see that the font is not loaded, but I don't see why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
```

Comment: This works.  I have two follow up questions though: why is the first fa needed? when I look at the dev tools I still don't see the font files loaded, why is that? (In plunk preview mode)

Comment: using a parent class like .fa makes it harder for any css you already have to conflict. If fa-remove was already dedicated to your remove buttons for example, you might have completely unintended side effects after adding Font Awesome to your html. Glyphicons does the same thing.

Comment: If you take a look into the `fontawesome.css` file you can see that `.fa` sets the `font-family` to FontAwesome whereas all subsequent classes like `fa-remove` only set the character to display.

Comment: @zisoft, I see that .fa has 'display: inline-block;' and .fa-remove doesn't have the 'display' at all.  Does that mean that I need the .fa class too if I want it to be displayed?

Comment: See it as inheritance (cascading). The base class `fa` sets all the required properties. Every other `fa-xxx` needs that properties to get displayed correctly. You always need the base class `fa`